# Is the array returned by scandir() a countable object?

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out why `count(scandir("/dirname"));` always evaluates to 0 when the number of files in the directory is not 0. When a person goes onto my page, the following script executes at the top of the page:

```
<?php 
    setcookie("user", count(scandir("/players")));
?>
```

The directory contains 2 files. But `count(scandir("/dirname"));` still evaluates to 0. Is it because the array

```
player0.json
player1.json
```

returned by `scandir()` is a non countable object?

Comment: `scandir` returns an array. And you can execute `count()` over an array. How do you check that scandir returns 0 for you?

Comment: The array is just an ordinary array, so yes, it's `count`able. Sounds like you don't have read permissions on the folder in question. Check your permissions.

Comment: @lolbas i check the cookie value using chrome dev tools

Comment: I hope you are aware that `scandir("/players")` tries to read the files from the directory `players` located in the root of the file system and, most probably, that directory does not exist. I guess you want to scan a directory located inside your project directory.

Comment: @axiac would `count(scandir(getcwd() ."/players"));` work?

Comment: `getcwd()` returns the current working directory which usually is **not** the directory where the PHP file is located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the directory `players` is located in the same directory where the PHP file is located, you can simply pass `'players'` to `scandir()` or other function that works with directories. It is a relative path and most of the times it works.

But, in order to make sure your code always works, you better use the PHP [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) `__DIR__` to generated the full path of the `players` directory:

```
scandir(__DIR__.'/players')
```

should return an array that contains the names of the files stored in the `players` directory and passing this array to `count()` will correctly return the number of values it contains (as it also does now).

---

To answer the question in the title, on success [`scandir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) returns a PHP [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and the PHP arrays are always [countable](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php).

Answer (score -2):

Either you don't have `Read/Write Permission` on that folder Or you are `Trying to access the directory which isn't in the Root Scope`. I suggest you to give the `Relative Path` for "/players directory" instead of `Absolute Path`.